# How to check the user enter a address URL on browser and click on a bookmark?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As title,

I want to get event when the user enter a URL on browser and the user click a URl on bookmark by javascript.

How to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Not possible. Period.**

**Reason**: Both do not generate referrers. If a link has been clicked from somewhere, it would be possible to determine using the `document.referrer`.

This same page, clicked from the list of questions in jQuery:

[image]

This same page, entered by copy paste or by bookmark:

[image]

Comment: @DzungNguyen Good to know.